# How to conditionally write a file into a VM using Openstack Heat templates

Tags: openstack, openstack-heat

I am able to find use-cases to use conditions for creating a resource, in resource properties or in output section.
I am looking for an heat template example code to write a file into the Server  based on condition. I want to copy a certain file only if a condition is true.
Is it possible using Heat Templates?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "Fn::FindInMap" , a sample template using the [same](https://github.com/openstack/heat-templates/blob/master/cfn/deb/WordPress_Single_Instance_deb.template)